# Talk back access to phone when switched on

Tags: talk-back

How can I override Talk back on my samsung galaxy J1 phone. When I switch on my phone I cannot access my menu as the voice keeps telling me to press the select menu twice

Answer (score 0):

That is how Talkback works.

Single tap to select an item in the screen, double tap to achieve actual tap action (double tap corresponds to single tap when Talkback is enabled.) Also, double finger touch scrolling will let you scroll list views. By this way you can reach to Talkback settings and disable it.